# Важна ли версия XCode?

Tags: xcode, ios

Вопрос к яблочникам, сейчас переходим на iOS приложения. Посмотрел существующие версии XCode собственно многие подерживаются только последними версиями макоса. У меня сразу два вопроса.

1. Важна ли версия XCode при кодинге? Или тут случай как в андроиде: если хотим поддержку всех девайсов, пишем под самую низкую версию (в андроиде пишем под 1.5, получаем поддержку всех), как тут обстоят дела?
2. Хотим купить iMaс, там вроде снежный барс 10.6, с MacOS практически не работал, есть ли там возможность как-то обновлять систему до последней версии, вроде под iOS 5 уже Lion нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Версия XCode при кодинге не важна, XCode – это просто IDE, так же как и Eclipse, но в XCode 4 появилось много важных и полезных фич, сильно упрощающих жизнь.
2. Версия SDK (то, что вы сравнивали с андроидом), важна. Если вы пишите под версию 4.x, соответственно некоторое API на устройствах с прошивкой 3.х работать не будет, но так как девайсы от эпл, в отличии от андроида, самообновляются, то проблем с этим значительно меньше, т.к. у всех практически, стоит последняя прошивка, в исключение попадают старые девайсы: iPhone 1/2G, т.к. они не могут быть обновлены до версии 4.х, а осенью выходит iOS 5, который так же не будет поддерживать iPhone 3G.
3. Возможность обновлять систему конечно же есть, не знаю точно, нужно будет обновлять MacOS до Lion для поддержки iOS5, но даже если и так, то вы просто покупаете*(качаете с торрента)* диск с MacOS Lion и ставите егео на свой iMac и все.

Comment: 2.2. Приложение обязательно должно работать на последней версии iOS

Answer (score 0):

Насчет поддержки разных версий iOS:
вообще как советуют - всегда использовать новейшую версию SDK, но при этом (для поддержки старых устройств) устанавливать Deployment Target на iOS 3.x.
При этом, конечно, нужно будет каждый раз при использовании какой-нибудь *подозрительной* фичи проверять, поддерживает ли ее устройство или нет. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version) рассказано как это делать.